# How to handle video with different frame rates in Lightworks?

Tags: framerate, slowmotion, lightworks

Most video editing software allows me to import video of different frame rates, but Lightworks either does not have this feature still, or I cannot find it (on Lightworks or on the internet).  Does anyone have any tips?  I would really like to use Lightworks, but using multiple cameras (one of them being an iPhone), and shooting in slow motion, makes this a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will need to transcode all clips with frame rates not matching the project's frame rate:

> If the frame rate is of a clip is not compatible with your project, it
>   displays in red.  You will be unable to import the clip into your
>   project.  Clips with incompatible frame rates may be playable in a new
>   project set to the  same frame rate as the clip.

(page 40; [User Guide](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_lwks&view=download&Itemid=206))

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), a command line tool, to transcode such clips with commands of the form

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 8 -r 25 -c:a copy -map 0 input25.mov
```

**Edit**: should make clear that `25` should be replaced with the framerate of the project. NTSC 30d i.e. 29.97 fps is denoted as `30000/1001` and 23.976 as `24000/1001`.

Answer (score 1):

in the latest version it is now possible to import mixed framerates